# what can be done to avoid following hidden mistake due to autoboxing while working with Records

Tags: java, java-8, autoboxing

Sometimes I write small scripts, either to manage records in DB or to produce some data for reporting purposes.

Most of the time we use `Long` type for ID of user entity. If I do something like following:

```
List<Long> listOfLong = Arrays.asList(1L, 2L, 3L);
System.out.println(listOfLong.contains(2));
```

it returns `false` but for this:

```
System.out.println(integers.contains(2L));
```

it returns `true`.

Shouldn't we get a compile time error for such thing ?

Comment: No, since we should have several implementation  for `contains` method. but now it take `Object` as argument.

Comment: You could write your own IdList class with a contains-Function only for Longs

Comment: I didn't downvote, but why not using `Long.valueOf(2)`? 2 can also be a parameter, also why you call it integers when it's longs?

Comment: @user7294900 var name changed, yeah it's the right way to get Long wrapper for this comparison but this first thing comes handy is passing literal directly sicnce it's not complaining and we are lazy ;)

Comment: **2 can also be a parameter** exactly my point @user7294900

Comment: Aside: for long literals, prefer a capital `L` suffix instead of a lower-case `l` which in some fonts is easily confused with the numeral one `1`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason that you don't a compilation error is that the the signature for `contains` in `Collection<E>` is defined as:

```
boolean contains(Object o)
```

That's right, `Object`.  Not `contains(<E> o)`.

(Why did they define it this way?  I understand that it is for compatibility with versions of Java prior to Java 5 when the collection types were not generic.  If they had redefined the `contains` method in Java 5 to only allow `<E>` arguments it would have broken a lot of code that worked in earlier versions of Java.)

So, as far as the compiler is concerned, an `Integer` instance is an appropriate argument type when calling `contains` on a `List<Long>`.

> Shouldn't we get a compile time error for such thing ?

No.  It is valid Java.

(If you mean "should" in the sense of "it would be better if" ... then I agree.  But `contains` was defined this way for a reason, and there is no going back.)

> What can be done to avoid the hidden mistake

Try using a static code analyzer like FindBugs or PMD.  I don't know for sure if these tools would detect this particular mistake, but they may find other mistakes.

Apart from that:

- More testing.
- Change your codebase to use a custom type for the ids.  One that cannot be autoboxed / unboxed.  (A lot of work, and the cure may be worse than the disease ... as they say.)

Comment: There are practical considerations not only for preexisting code. A signature `contains(E)` would imply that you can’t query any `List<? extends X>` whether it contains a particular `X`. Not semantically, of course, as you can still perform the desired query manually with a loop. So it would only complicate programming without preventing such errors in general. By the way, the Netbeans IDE shows a warning, even without additional audit tools.

Comment: Hmmm ... perhaps `contains(<? extends E> o)` would be better (hypothetically).

Comment: This doesn’t work. When you can’t name the type, you can’t provide an object guaranteed to be of that particular type. (Mind that the compiler can not distinguish the different implications of `contains(E)` and `add(E)`). You can use `? super E` do specify that the type could be a super type, so it can consume objects (the PECS rule), but then, the effective result is not different to `contains(Object)`.

Answer (score 1):

You asked:

> Shouldn't we get a compile time error for such thing?

Yes, I would prefer that and maybe it would be that way, if Java were done from scratch again today.

If this were a serious issue in my code, I would create a wrapper for the number, e.g.

```
class UserId {
  public UserId(long id) { ... }
  public long getId() { ... }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[contains](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#contains-java.lang.Object-) check using equals method on Object type parameter

> ```
>  boolean contains(Object o)
> ```
>
> list contains at least one element e such that `(o==null ? e==null : o.equals(e))`

If you don't remember/sure you will set value as Long before using it

You can cast it first to long, you can use `Long.valueOf`

```
List<Long> listOfLong = Arrays.asList(1l, 2l, 3l);
System.out.println(listOfLong.contains(Long.valueOf(2)));
```

Or make value 2 sent as method parameter so it will be Long in method signature

```
public void myMethod(Long number) {
     List<Long> listOfLong = Arrays.asList(1l, 2l, 3l);
     System.out.println(listOfLong.contains(number));
}
```

Comment: OP has not asked for solution! _isn't it good to get an error at compile time for such thing ?_

Comment: @HadiJ added about using contains

Answer (score 0):

To add to the other, correct, answers: while it's not a compile error (since nothing in JLS is violated), your tool might raise a warning. Eclipse will tell you:

> Unlikely argument type `int` for `contains(Object)` on a `Collection<Long>`
>
> Unlikely argument type `long` for `contains(Object)` on a `Collection<Integer>`